# Firebase security rules based on userId attribute

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Please see my [Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzFFL.png)

```
"errands" : {
  "-K0dGrAo6vSqKHRwiAJQ" : {
    "name" : "Milk",
    "permissions" : [ {
      "userId" : "ca8d19cb-f1d7-4bfd-9471-fb88c469b6ca"
    }, {
      "userId" : "ef4bacad-d713-47ac-853e-b3ec3e4bf684"
    } ],
    "store" : "Coscto"
  },
  "-K0dHsTSyrfm3uZjptNN" : {
    "name" : "Milk",
    "permissions" : [ {
      "userId" : "ca8d19cb-f1d7-4bfd-9471-fb88c469b6ca"
    }, {
      "userId" : "ef4bacad-d713-47ac-853e-b3ec3e4bf684"
    } ],
    "store" : "Coscto"
  }
}
```

I am trying to provide access based on userId attribute. It says access denied.

```
".read": "root.child('errands').child('permissions').child('userId').val() === auth.uid ",
```

Comment: {
  "errands": 
  {
        "K0dGrAo6vSqKHRwiAJQ": {
                "name": "milk",
                "store": "costco",
                "permissions": {
                  "0":{"userId":"123123"},
                  "1":{"userId":"3424234"}
                }
        }
  }      
 
}

Comment: "It says access denied" What operation are you trying to perform when you get this error? My best bet is that you're trying to read/query `errands`, which will not work unless the user has read access on `errands`. See rules are not filters: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter